# Выполнение команд CMD с помощью ShellExecute

Tags: delphi, cmd

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые эксперты. Столкнулся с необходимостью использовать в проекте команды виндовой консоли CMD. Вызываю нужную команду с помощью ShellExecute:

```
ShellExecute(0, 'open', 'cmd.exe', '/c regsvr32 /s some.dll', nil, SW_SHOW);
```

Результат нулевой. Пробовал вариации на тему HInstance и Self.Handle в качестве первого параметра, пробовал оборачивать параметры в PChar и PWideChar, ничего не изменилось: появляется окно cmd, но никаких инструкций туда не попадает. Решил, что возможно ошибся в самой команде cmd, упростил задачу:

```
ShellExecute(0, 'open', 'cmd.exe', 'dir', nil, SW_SHOW);
```

Результат тот-же. Подскажите что не так

Answer (score 1):

Как выяснилось, дело в ключах. Рабочие конструкции

```
ShellExecute(0, 'open', 'cmd.exe', '/k regsvr32 some.dll', nil, SW_SHOW);
```

и

```
ShellExecute(0, 'open', 'cmd.exe', '/k dir', nil, SW_SHOW);
```

соответственно. в общем, тему можно считать закрытой.